# Google Voice messenger notification problem

Tags: iphone, sms, notifications, text

I have an iPhone 4 with the Google Voice messenger app. However I don't get notifications at all; I've tried everything! If I want to check if I recieved a text I have to go into the app and press the refresh button. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It would be probably a bug with the app. Can you check that you have notifications on for this app, by going into the following setting:

Home Screen > Settings > Notifications > GV Messenger.

Additionally the GV Messenger is not the official Google voice app. You may want to use [the official Google Voice app.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524?mt=8)